# Is there a way to reach users that download an app but never open it?

Tags: android

There is a lot of info about abandonment rate of apps. Users only open an app once, etc. However what about users that never open an app?

We don't know anything about them. We don't have an email address or GCM/FCM token. Receivers for BOOT_COMPLETED, etc are not registered.

They have at least shown some interest in the app. Seems like an untapped opportunity.

Comment: I think the idea is that it's sort of naggy. The user DOES see is the "new app" icon as part of the OS.

I'm not sure what a good UX designer would do here.  I think it'd be cool if the OS sent a notification saying "Here are X apps you've downloaded but not used" periodically, but i don't think that exists.

Comment: "_users that never open an app_" Where do you get this information? Are you sure it is correct? May be the app was opened in offline mode or you don't get the info because of other reasons.

Comment: I would show a notification. I do that when a user has opened the app once. That works well.

Comment: I get this information from the Google Play Store and Google Analytics. There is a big gap between installs and a 1 time open. I mentioned this to my colleagues and they said... oh yeah, I install apps all the time that look interesting but don't have time to try them out at that moment and then forget about them.